# sep='-' returns invalid syntax after working perfectly fine

Tags: python, syntax

Hi everyone I'm new to programming but I'm picking it up pretty quickly. In my class we need to create different programs in the same file. The error in question appears in a program that was finished but when I completed the assignment I went to test the entire thing and this comes up all of a sudden. Here's the code:

```
def make_string_sandwich(string1, string2):
''' ????
Parameters:
    string1 - outside string
    string2 - inside string
Variables:
    <string_sandwich - line of strings in the order string1-string2-string1>
'''
string_sandwich = (string1, string2, string1, sep='-')
return string_sandwich

assertEqual(make_string_sandwich('bbb','a'), 'bbb-a-bbb')
```

The error is the = in the line:

```
string_sandwich = (string1, string2, string1, sep='-')
```

After I finished writing the code and moved on I never touched it but all of a sudden this happened. if I remove the sep='-' the output for the assertEqual example is:

```
('bbb', 'a', 'bbb')
```

Other programs I've made that use the sep= function still works perfectly. I commented out everything else in the document to isolate this program to make sure it wasn't future code screwing with it but that didn't work. The only other ways I've thought of writing it as are:

```
string_sandwich = (string1, string2, string1), sep='-'
string_sandwich = ((string1, string2, string1), sep='-')
```

but none of that works (not that I thought it would). The solution to the only relevant thread I could find was that python was using version 2 and not 3 and gives a way to check the version. When I did this the output is:

```
3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:37:12) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
```

so I know I'm using the latest version of python. I thought I was done with this assignment and now this is happening and its due tomorrow. PLEASE HELP ME!! I greatly appreciate any and all help I can get with this problem.

Comment: As a side note, 3.3.5 is not the latest version of Python; 3.4 has been out since March, and 3.4.1 since May.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sep` is an argument to the `print` function. To do what you want, you have to use the `join` function:

```
return '-'.join((string1, string2, string1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! we havn't learned the join function yet so I'm not sure what happened to make the original stop workin yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
def make_string_sandwich(string1, string2):
    ''' ????
    Parameters:
        string1 - outside string
        string2 - inside string
    Variables:
        <string_sandwich - line of strings in the order string1-string2-string1>
    '''
    string_sandwich = (string1, string2, string1)
    return "{}-{}-{}".format(*string_sandwich)
```

If you wanted to use `sep` you would have to `print` the output:

```
def make_string_sandwich(string1, string2):
    ''' ????
    Parameters:
        string1 - outside string
        string2 - inside string
    Variables:
        <string_sandwich - line of strings in the order string1-string2-string1>
    '''
    print(string1, string2, string1,sep="-")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I wanted to use the 'print(string1, string2, string1, sep='-')' solution but when I ran the assertEqual function with that code the computed answer was 'None'

Comment: Functions that dont have a return value return None by default